# Error when using REVTeX 4.1

Tags: errors, revtex

I've tried to upgrade to REVTeX 4.1 but am getting compile error even with the simplest document:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\filelist
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

produces:

```
...snip...
! LaTeX Error: Command \url already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
...snip...
```

Did I install improperly, or is this a bug?

EDIT (Requested file list):

```
 *File List*
revtex4-1.cls    2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentation)
  aps4-1.rtx
aps10pt4-1.rtx
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
     url.sty    1999/03/02  ver 1.4  Verb mode for urls, email addresses, and file names
  natbib.sty    2007/02/05 8.0 (PWD)
revsymb4-1.sty    2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentation)
 ***********
```

Comment: Did you delete any stray `.aux` files? Could you `\listfiles` for us: I have no issues.

Comment: I don't get any error. Can you show the part of the log file that you get from `*File List*` to the end when adding `\listfiles` at the very beginning of the document?

Comment: @JosephWright and egerg: Done.

Comment: Do you have any `.bbl` file from a previous version of your document? If so, try deleting the `.bbl` file.

Comment: I think that I had the class installed incorrectly or had some lingering .aux file. anyhow, I recompiled on a different machine and it worked fine...sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

(More of a comment, but too long)

This is 'works for me' with TeX Live 2012, and I get file list

```
 *File List*
revtex4-1.cls    2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for 
documentation)
  aps4-1.rtx
aps10pt4-1.rtx
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
revsymb4-1.sty    2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for
 documentation)
```

My immediate suspicion would be the version of `natbib` you are using.